# Is [azure-mcd] the same as [azure-germany]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Currently there are two tags: [azure-mcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-mcd) and [azure-germany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-germany).

Since "mcd" seems to be "Microsoft Cloud Deutschland" (aka: Microsoft Cloud Germany) and the description of [azure-germany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-germany) states

> For questions related with the German Azure Datacenter

Currently a edit is pending for [azure-mcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-mcd) which sets the description to

> For questions related with the MCD (Microsoft Cloud Deutschland) Azure Datacenter

These two tags could be synonyms for each other, but I'm not deep enough in the azure community to be sure. Could someone confirm that and maybe make the two tags a synonym of each other?

Comment: Isn't azure the same everywhere just localized?

Comment: What is so special about the programming in Germany that it warrants their own tag?

Comment: The question I checked seem more like Microsoft support type of questions then really related to programming with that regional azure instance.

Comment: [Azure Germany](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/clouds/germany/) deals with EU laws. Whether or not the tags will be used frequently remains to be seen, but I'm not opposed to a tag existing for it.

Comment: I actually don't know. Just stumbled over the tags when reviewing edits. There might be some legal things for personalized data that has to be stored inside the EU?

Comment: @Stijn fair enough but then the questions still need to be on topic. If we are going to handle here what ever they come up with in Bruxelles we're screwed ...

Comment: I've merged both into azure as I'm not sure they're really required. If they pop up again we can readdress it then.

Comment: @JonClements Maybe you should have given the community some time to discuss this? ...

Comment: I've pinged one of the users that appeared to be from Microsoft to comment here.

Comment: @Stijn seemed fairly clear cut to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read their [overview sheet](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=839380&clcid=0x409) and other than meeting data regulations by EU and location of the data centers, the germany flavor of azure isn't, from a programmer POV, any different than azure in other countries. It should be just merged with the azure main tag, after we clean up whatever off topic question it may have.

The selling points according to them:

> Azure Germany is a differentiated option from these with separate accounts and pricing. It delivers our industry-leading services from German datacenters, with data residency in Germany, and strict data access and control measures provided through a unique data trustee model governed under German law. Your choice between Azure Germany and other Azure regions should be informed by:
>
> - Data residency and sovereignty needs
> - Public sector or restricted industry requirements
> - Compliance requirements
> - Eligibility as an EU/EFTA organization
> - Location of your organization and customers
> - Cost and budget considerations

I don't see anything unique to software development.